# Emacs yet another snippet extension php-mode

Tags: emacs, code-snippets, php-mode

I'm new to using emacs, and I am currently having some trouble with the 'yet another snippet' extension.

I am trying to do some work using the php-mode major mode. Unfortunately, it is based on the cc-mode, which means the snippet extension is looking at the C and PHP snippets.

Is there any way to just load the PHP snippets instead of loading them from both C and PHP?

Answer (score 1):

the [docs](http://yasnippet.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/snippet-organization.html) indicate placing an empty .yas-parents file into the php-mode snippet directory works.